# Can Invention designs be re-used?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

In the Invention rules, it says that there are two phases to making an invention, Design and Construction.  The rules also say that inventions are one-use; they work for one scene and then break.  However, the rules are sort of unclear on what happens to your designs once you've made your invention.  Are you able to re-use designs?  Once you have a design, do you ever need to spend the time and make a design check for that particular invention again?  If not, why not?

Furthermore, can this be applied to Rituals?  Once I've designed a ritual, can I spend the 10 minutes per point and make an Expertise: Magic check whenever I want to cast the ritual again?

This question is specifically asking about M&M 3e.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to page 125 of the *Gadget Guides* book:

> An inventor can keep an existing invention running by either taking the time needed to design it (hours equal to its point cost) to do maintenance and repairs and making a DC 10 + point cost Technology check, or by spending a hero point.

According to page 128:

> At the Gamemaster’s discretion, characters can retain and reuse successful ritual designs, essentially skipping this step for future uses of the ritual, and just constructing and performing it in the future. This requires some bookkeeping in terms of what rituals the character has designed, and it’s up to the GM whether or not ritual designs can be shared or used amongst other ritualists.

Some GMs might only allow this if you have documentation onhand (or succeed in a memory check) though, which means having your spell library burn down could be a major problem.

I would personally allow a person to use someone else's pre-designed invention or ritual as well, albeit with a skill check to correctly interpret the instructions.

Comment: With regards to using an existing ritual or design (assuming the Ritualist/Inventor wrote it down and kept it, instead of just scribbling on a napkin that's since been lost) I would say that my players would need to spend rounds equal to the point cost studying the plans and make a skill check before building/performing - equivalent to using a Hero Point to speed that step.  This would represent the character taking a few minutes to refresh themselves on what needs to be done.